# Variable prints intended(length of a string) value only in a particular cout statement

Tags: c++, string, vector, string-length

`minlen` variable prints only in the `middle` `cout` and gives a random value when used anywhere else

```cpp
class Solution
{
    public:
    string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& strs)
    {
        int sofar = sizeof(strs) / 8;
        int len[sofar], i, j, minlen;
        string newstr = "";

        for(i = 0; i < sofar; i++)
        {
            len[i] = strs[i].length();
            if(len[i] < minlen)
                minlen = len[i];
        }

        //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   HERE    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        cout << minlen << endl;
        cout << "sofar : " << sofar << endl << "minlen : " << minlen << endl;
        cout << minlen << endl;

        /*for(i=0;i<mlen;i++)
        {
             cout<<"outer"<<endl;
            for(j=0;j<sofar-1;j++)
            {
                cout<<"middle"<<endl;
                if(strs[j][i]==strs[j+1][i])
                {   newstr=newstr+strs[j+1];
                    cout<<"innermost"<<endl;
                }
            }
        }*/

        return newstr;
    }
};
```

Comment: You don't initialize `minlen`, so `if(len[i]<minlen)` is undefined behavior

Comment: Also `sizeof(strs) / 8` is definitely not what you want (why the / 8 anyway?). You want `strs.size()`

Comment: changing the sizeof(strs) / 8 to strs.size() fixed it

Comment: @madlading If your are satisfied by an answer, please accept it by clicking on the tickbox on its left.

Answer (score 0):

```
int len[sofar], i, j, minlen;
```

Here `minlen` is declared but left uninitialized, thus giving a random value of whatever was left on the stack at that point.

```
            if(len[i] < minlen)
                minlen = len[i];
```

The first time this `if` statement is executed, `minlen` is still a random value.  It is only **set** when that test succeeds.

Comment: You may want to address the problem in `int sofar = sizeof(strs) / 8;` as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a serious problem besides the `sizeof` in this code.

You don't initialize `minlen` before using it and hence **while it may seem to work, it is not working and is undefined behavior**.

Since, it looks like you want to find the string with the smallest length and store its length in `minlen`, one fix can be to assign `minlen` to length of string at 0th index (or any index for that matter) by

```
    minlen = strs[0].length();

    for(i = 0; i < sofar; i++)
        {
            len[i] = strs[i].length();
            if(len[i] < minlen)
                minlen = len[i];
        }
```

This doesn't change anything to the functionality of your code but removes the undefined behavior.

Also, `sizeof` returns the number of bytes in the vector while `size()` returns the number of items in your vector. That's why `.size()` worked.